# How can I print selected columns from a CSV file in python

Tags: python, csv

I have this code:

```
file=open("database.txt","r")
list_0=file.readlines()

item=input("enter station name: ")
for element in list_0:
    a=element.index(' ')
    if element.find(item.lower())!=-1:
        print(element[:a]+" -----> "+element[a:])
```

Result from above I want:

```
enter station name: ambala

14096 himalyan-queen

12498 shan-e-punjab

22461 shri-shakti
```

But it is showing this result:

```
enter station name: ambala

14096 himalyan-queen new-delhi,ambala,chandigarh,kalka

12498 shan-e-punjab new-delhi,ambala,ludhiana,amritsar

22461 shri-shakti new-delhi,ambala,ludhiana,katra
```

anybody knows how to do this?

Here is the data from CSV file(you can see delimiter is " "-space)

```
14096 himalyan-queen new-delhi,ambala,chandigarh,kalka
12498 shan-e-punjab new-delhi,ambala,ludhiana,amritsar
22461 shri-shakti new-delhi,ambala,ludhiana,katra
12412 intercity amritsar,ludhiana,chandigarh
```

Comment: Could you include a few lines from `database.txt`? EDIT: I'd also check out the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module from the standard library

Comment: so i have added some of the lines from CSV file.

Comment: Your data should be seperated via comma [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180). Doenst matter in your case :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should find the second space.

try the following piece of code:

```
file=open("C:\Users\Anything\Desktop\stackoverflow\db.txt","r")
list_0=file.readlines()

item=raw_input("enter station name: ")
for element in list_0:
    a=element.index(' ')
    if element.find(item.lower())!=-1:
        element1 = element[a:].strip()
        b = element1.index(' ')
        print (element[:a] + ' '+ element1[:b])
```

Comment: perfect. I just want this answer without importing csv. thanks! buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
item=input("enter station name: ")
for element in list_0:
    a=element.split(' ')
    if element.find(item.lower())!=-1:
        print(a[0], a[1])
```

This modification will compare your input against the entire string, but only display the number and the first part of the string part, which is separated by a whitespace.

Comment: it gives    1 -----> 4
    1 -----> 2
    2 -----> 2

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [csv library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

item = 'ambala' #for demonstration purpose, get it like you did before

with open('database.txt', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in spamreader:
        if item in row[2]:
            print(row[0] + ' ' + row[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you print you use:

```
element[:a] // will print all the elements that are from the begining of the list until 'a' index
```

and

```
element[a:] // will print all the elements that are from 'a' index of the list until the end this is why you print all the elements 'himalyan-queen new-delhi,ambala,chandigarh,kalka'
```

to solve the problem try this

```
file=open("database.txt","r")
list_0=file.readlines()

item=input("enter station name: ")
for element in list_0:
    splitted_elem=element.split(' ')
    if item.lower() in splitted_elem[2]:
        print(splitted_elem[0]+" -----> "+splitted_elem[1])
```

Comment: it only prints element before a i.e element[a-1] which is 6,8 and 1. and a space which is element[a]

Comment: you are right. Now it will work solving your problem

Comment: error with contain function "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains' "

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('database.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

station_name = 'ambala'
for line in lines:
    spaced = line.split()
    commad = spaced[2].split(',')
    if station_name in commad[1]:
        print(spaced[0], '---->', spaced[1])
```

The above should result to:

```
λ python sample.py
14096 ----> himalyan-queen
12498 ----> shan-e-punjab
22461 ----> shri-shakti
```

Comment: if i put any other station i.e katra, new-delhi. It doesn't give any result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer using the csv module and using "with" statements to open and close files

```
import csv

with open('names.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    item=input("enter station name: ")
    for row in reader:
        if item in row[2].split(','):
            print(row[0], row[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by other use the csv library, so you are able to read lines as list:

```
['14096 himalyan-queen new-delhi', 'ambala', 'chandigarh', 'kalka']
```

Then, you can easily access the required column by index.

This is another possible implementation:

```
import csv

item = 'ambala' # input etc.
with open('database.txt', newline='') as csvfile:
  reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
  for row in reader:
    if row[1] == item: # look just on the second column, but you can customise: if item in row[1:]:
      a = row[0].index(' ')
      print((row[0][:a] + " -----> " + row[0][a:]))

# 14096 ----->  himalyan-queen new-delhi
# 12498 ----->  shan-e-punjab new-delhi
# 22461 ----->  shri-shakti new-delhi
```